# Where are plugins found in Joomla 4?

Tags: plugin, administrator, joomla-4.x

I'm working with the Joomla 4 alpha 7, and I don't see anywhere to enable / disable plugins. Are plugins not enabled yet?

[edited to add alpha, not beta!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably work with **Joomla 4 (alpha)** as beta does not seem to be yet available. The plugins in Joomla 4 (alpha 7 latest) are at **administrator->system->manage->plugins**.

Comment: I'm not a major fan of this new System page at all. It makes finding things a lot harder than before

Comment: @Lodder - I had the same thougth when I first opened that :) Strange structure and layout.